# How to unsubscribe to OneSignal Programmatically in android studio

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I have made a news app that send the users oneSignal notification and works fine ,but i have a problem with making the user controlling whether receiving the notification or not but i can't find how to make unsubscribe to OneSignal Programmatically and if the user do that by pressing a button ,he will no longer receive any notification , any one can help please am still beginner in android studio .

Comment: This suggests its about Android Studio an IDE, rather than Android programming - suggest renaming. Also please provide examples of what you have already tried to make clearer to someone who could help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
```

setSubscription METHOD

> You can call this method with false, to opt users out of receiving all notifications through OneSignal.
>       You can pass true later to opt users back into notifications.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--setsubscription-

Answer (score 15):

On OneSignal 4.0.0, `setSubscription(false)` was replaced with

```
OneSignal.disablePush(true)
```